# How to set project ID to avoid warnings?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to set up a new Colaboratory notebook to analyze data we have in BigQuery. Following the sample document, I have my first code snippet as:

```
project_id = '<redacted>'
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

When I run that, I get the following warning, repeated twice:

```
WARNING:google.auth._default:No project ID could be determined from the credentials 
at GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS Consider setting the GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT 
environment variable
```

Attempting to set the project ID via `os.environ` does not work.

I also get this error every time I use pandas to execute a SQL statement, even though I am providing it, á la:

```
pd.io.gbq.read_gbq(sql, project_id=project_id, verbose=False, dialect='standard')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set up the environment for GCP call for specified project using

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"] = project_id
```

Comment: Thanks, this made my warnings go away without systematic change. very nice

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few questions here:

1. Why are you seeing these warnings?

   The messages you're seeing are log messages; if you're seeing them, it means either your code or code that you've called is calling something like [`logging.basicConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig). This will lead to log messages of sufficient level (`WARNING` by default) will be displayed to stderr, which is what's happening here.
2. What are these warnings about?

   The warning in this case is telling you that `google.auth` couldn't figure out a project; as it happens, the message about an environment variable is actually spurious, since the named var isn't read in this path. I've [filed a bug upstream](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/issues/221).

You have two easy options:

1. Turn off logging (how you do this will vary based on how you've enabled it). You can also selectively set the log level to something else.
2. Ignore these messages. (They're harmless, but annoying.)

I filed a [colab issue](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1) to track making this less annoying.